# Apache http + Jboss + mod_proxy or mod_proxy_html

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, jboss

I am developing a Java EE web app running on **JBOSS**. I want users to authenticate in my web app using their smartcard's X.509 authentication certificate yo access the web content.

I have decided to use **Apache** http server with JBOSS using **mod_proxy**, to be able to use Apache's mod_ssl. I would like to know if mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http is the same? If not what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation:

**Apache Module mod_proxy**

> This module implements a proxy/gateway for Apache. It implements
>   proxying capability for **AJP13 (Apache JServe Protocol version 1.3),
>   FTP, CONNECT (for SSL), HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, and HTTP/1.1**. The module
>   can be configured to connect to other proxy modules for these and
>   other protocols.
>
> Apache's proxy features are divided into several modules in addition
>   to mod_proxy: **mod_proxy_http**, mod_proxy_ftp, mod_proxy_ajp,
>   mod_proxy_balancer, and mod_proxy_connect. Thus, if you want to use
>   one or more of the particular proxy functions, load mod_proxy and the
>   appropriate module(s) into the server (either statically at
>   compile-time or dynamically via the LoadModule directive).

**Apache Module mod_proxy_http**

> This module requires the service of **mod_proxy**. It provides the
>   features used for proxying HTTP and HTTPS requests. mod_proxy_http
>   supports HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1. It does not provide any
>   caching abilities. If you want to set up a caching proxy, you might
>   want to use the additional service of the mod_cache module.
>
> Thus, in order to get the ability of handling HTTP proxy requests,
>   mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http have to be present in the server.

In summary, mod_proxy_http can be used only to handle HTTP and HTTPS requests proxying and this required mod_proxy (provide features to other modules)